# Double looping for inset plots using ggplot in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, graphics, nested-loops

I am trying to run a loop over the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

#Setup of Variables
N <- 199
K <- N+1
x <- rep(0,N)
x[1] <- 0.5
g <- 3.84
time <- c(1:K)

for (t in 1:N){
  x[t+1] = g*x[t]*(1-x[t])
}

A <- data.frame(time,x)

#create separate plots 1 & 2 --> combine into plot3 using ggdraw()
plot1 <- ggplot(data=A, aes(x=time, y=x)) + geom_line(color="blue") + xlim(0,150) + ylab("Fish Stock") + theme_classic()

plot2 <- ggplot(data=A, aes(x=time, y=x)) + geom_line(color="forestgreen") + xlim(8,15) + theme(legend.position="none", axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), axis.line=element_line(colour="black"), panel.background=element_rect(fill="white",colour="white"))

plot3 <- 
  ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(plot1) + 
  draw_plot(plot2, .68, .68, .3, .3) #insetplot, x, y, width, height

plot3
```

Which creates the following graphic:

[image]

What I want to do with this, is nest this loop within another that loops through a vector of values for `g`. My attempt at this code is as follows:

```
G <- c(2.7, 2.9, 3.0, 3.5, 3.82, 3.83, 3.84, 3.85)

#Loop --> creation of x, dataframe, insetplots
for (g in G) {
  for (t in 1:N){
    x[t+1] = g*x[t]*(1-x[t])
  }

  A <- data.frame(time,x)

  plot1 <- ggplot(data=A, aes(x=time, y=x)) + geom_line(color="blue") + xlim(0,150) + ylab("Fish Stock") + theme_classic()
  plot2 <- ggplot(data=A, aes(x=time, y=x)) + geom_line(color="forestgreen") + xlim(8,15) + theme(legend.position="none", axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), axis.line=element_line(colour="black"), panel.background=element_rect(fill="white",colour="white"))
  plot3 <- 
  ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(plot1) + 
  draw_plot(plot2, .68, .68, .3, .3) #insetplot, x, y, width, height

  png(file = paste0("Fish-Stock-Inset_", g, ".png"))
  plot3
  dev.off()
}
```

However, I get a series of blank images. The saving of the plots is correct as I get the properly named files, but the graphs themselves are missing. I am almost certain that the issue falls with my placement of `A <- data.frame(time,x)` after the initial `for (t in 1:N)` loop.

I am sorry that this is simply a debugging question, but I hope it will be helpful for others running into this same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem arises because the plot3 is only evaluated at the end of the for loop (called lazy evaluation in R).

Try this below, where I use ggsave to render the plot and note to declare your x inside the loop:

```
G <- c(2.7, 2.9, 3.0, 3.5, 3.82, 3.83, 3.84, 3.85)

#Loop --> creation of x, dataframe, insetplots
for (g in G) {
  x <- rep(0,N)
  x[1] <- 0.5
  for (t in 1:N){
    x[t+1] = g*x[t]*(1-x[t])
  }

  A <- data.frame(time,x)

  plot1 <- ggplot(data=A, aes(x=time, y=x)) + geom_line(color="blue") + xlim(0,150) + ylab("Fish Stock") + theme_classic()
  plot2 <- ggplot(data=A, aes(x=time, y=x)) + geom_line(color="forestgreen") + xlim(8,15) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
  axis.title.y=element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank(), 
  panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
  axis.line=element_line(colour="black"), 
  panel.background=element_rect(fill="white",colour="white"))
  plot3 <- 
    ggdraw() +
    draw_plot(plot1) + 
    draw_plot(plot2, .68, .68, .3, .3) #insetplot, x, y, width, height

  ggsave(plot3,file = paste0("Fish-Stock-Inset_", g, ".png"))
}
```